# Javascript global array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using an array to store formatted results from google's geocoding API. After the function call I use console.log to see the contents of the array, which is working correctly, but when I try to access an individual element it returns "undefined". When I check the array length as well, I get zero. Here is my code (addressInput is an object storing three addresses):

```
function startGeocode(addressInput) {
  var addressOut = [];
  var outString = "";
  var address = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < addressInput.length; i++) {
    address = addressInput[i].address + " " + addressInput[i].city + " " + addressInput[i].state + " " + addressInput[i].zip;
    geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function(results,status) {
      if(status == 'OK') {
        outString = "" + results[0].geometry.location;
        outString = outString.replace(/\(|\)|\s/g,'');
        outString = outString.replace(/\,/g,' ');
        addressOut.push(outString);
      } else {
        outString = "Error: " + status;
        addressOut.push(outString);
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(addressOut);
  console.log(addressOut[0]);
  console.log(addressOut.length);
}
```

The three console.log calls return the following:

```
/* (Using a codeblock for readability)
Array[0]
0:"(a correctly formatted latitude and longitude)"
1:"(a correctly formatted latitude and longitude)"
2:"(a correctly formatted latitude and longitude)"

addressOut[0]: undefined

addressOut.length: 0
*/
```

So my question is, why am I getting an array length of zero, and why am I not able to reference the elements of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using asynchronous function `geocoder.geocode`. That means that you are printing to console var before this function is finished. Use callback or promises.

Comment: maybe this cause error